# Using "modal push" to a viewController and not being able to add UINavigationItem-(Controller, Bar) at the top

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In my project I have **1** `viewController` which is being pushed with a "**modal push**" from all other `viewControllers`. I am trying to add a `UINavigationItem` (bar at the top) to it, but it is not working. I have a similar viewController at another place in my project and as far as I can see, I have done exactly the same thing with it and being able to add `UINavigationItem` to it?

Now I need help understanding WHY I am unable to add `UINavigationItem` to my viewController? I am trying with the following code:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.nextButton,  self.menuButton, nil];
```

I am not getting any errors or ANY indication of why it is not working on my viewController, simply nothing happens? Here is a screen of it: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2itisgp&s=6

The viewController is connected both to a `tabBar` and `UINavigationController` but it should not matter since I have decided to push it with "**modal**" ? If I use a normal "push" the `UINavigationItem` will appear and it will be linked to the rest of the app. But that is the problem, I want it to be a single slide with its own `UINavigationBar`(Item, controller) or whatever you call it. The reasoning behind this is far more complex to be explained here and will just bore people. So lets focus on *WHY* I am unable to add `UINavigationItem`(bar, controller) at this viewController when using "**Modal push**" ?????? Please enlighten me if you know anything!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "modal push". A push segue is only used by a navigation controller, any controller can present another one modally. If the controller that you're trying to add the navigation buttons to is not embedded in a navigation controller, then self.navigationItem will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to accomplish that:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootController:yourViewController];

[viewController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am not using any code, I am just using "modal" push via storyboard.... I have tried this code but same result, nothing happens:   ShowTaskViewController *detailViewController = [[ShowTaskViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]     initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES  completion:nil];
    [navController release];
    [detailViewController release];

Comment: UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve is not a tpye of `modalTransitionStyle`. Perhaps it has to do with that.

Comment: Nope, has nothing to do with it :/. My project looks like this TabBarController --> NavigationController --> FristViewController --(modal push from storyboard) --> viewController(this is the controller where I can not enable UINavigationItem).

Comment: @user1293618, why are you doing a modal segue to viewController when FirstViewController is embedded in a navigation controller? Just change the segue to "push".

Comment: It is a long story, but I want the viewController to allow both landscape/portrait mode and lock the rest of the viewControllers in the app to portrait only. Since my TabBarController is the initial-controller in my app everything will inherit from it. So in order to enable all this, my best bet is to make a modal push so it will not inherit from my TabBarController/NavigationControllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard, you have to embed a Navigation Controller directly to the presented modal controller (Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller)

Your Storyboard should looks like this :

```
FirstVC -> Navigation Controller -> SecondVC
```

Comment: My project looks like this now: TabBarController --> NavigationController --> FristViewController --(modal push from storyboard) --> SecondViewController(this is the controller where I can not enable UINavigationItem). It would be a quite big job for me to add another NavigationController between FristVC and SecondVC. Do you really think it can have anything to do with this? :S

Comment: Ye don't worry, this is a normal situation when working with storyboard. Embedding a Navigation controller to your SecondVC acting exactly the same as programmatically by doing UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:secondVC]; and then presenting modally the navigation controller